# Sum of dot product numpy efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

How do I get the sum of a dot product efficiently

```
A =  np.random.rand(20,200)
x=  np.random.rand(20)
y=  np.random.rand(20)
num=  np.zeros(20)
for i in range (A.shape[0]):
    num[i] = np.sum(A.T[i,:].dot(x[i]+y[i]))
print num
```

Is there a way to find num without a for loop

Comment: Won't that be `for i in range (A.shape[1]):` instead because you have the iterator iterating along the columns of `A` with that transpose of `A`?

Comment: I think you need only `num=  np.zeros(20)`, right?

Comment: The question is, why are you using `dot` to do a scalar multiplication? `x[i] + y[i]` are scalars.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, no problem, we are trying to understand the intent of the OP.

Comment: Now you need to make num have 200 or remove the `.T`.

Comment: Could you fix that please?

Comment: @MadPhysicist x and y are 20 there sum will be a 20 while A is 20,200 so for a dot product I need it to be 200,20 hence .T

Comment: @AyaAbdelsalam If you are iterating along cols with that transpose, you would need `for i in range (A.shape[1]):` irrespective of the datasizes.

Comment: `A.T` is `200,20`, so `A.T[i]` is 20, but it's probably not what you want...

Comment: Also, `x[i] + y[i]` is a scalar, so there is no point in using `dot` given how your code is currently written. `x + y` is a vector.

Comment: @MadPhysicist A.T[1,:] would be 1,20 which you can then dot with x+y

Comment: Basically, barring the mismatch in indices, `num = sum(A.T * (x + y))` is what your code is currently doing.

Comment: @Divakar I had x,y, num should be 20 not 200 (I changed that )so A.shape[0] would  be correct however in this case your answer won't work

Comment: @AyaAbdelsalam. You should read what you posted very carefully and fix it. You are dotting with a scalar, not a vector here, you have some weird indexing going on and  am not sure if the size of A is not a typo at this point.

Comment: @MadPhysicist No x and y aren't scalar they are vector and so is A I am pretty sure its correct now I ran it, it gives me what I am expecting

Comment: You aren't dotting with `x + y`, you are dotting with `x[i] + y[i]`. I really suggest you read through the question you wrote and the comments that followed instead of arguing that there can't be anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
num = np.einsum('ji,i->i',A[:,:20],x+y)
```

That slicing of `[:,:20]` is needed because even though you are iterating along the rows of `A.T` with `A.T[i,:]` i.e. columns of `A`, you are not iterating through all of those columns.

Comment: I wrote the  sizes wrong the first time A.shape[0] is correct hiw ever x and y are (20,) not (200,)

Comment: this works perfectly I didnt know about the slicing thanks!